# Combining .png images to form a video in python(LOSSLESS FORM)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library, steganography

Can Anyone suggest how to combine multiple png images into a video in a lossless format in python? (Required for Video Steganography)

Comment: You can use `ffmpeg` with x264 lossless encoding and `-crf 0` like this https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#LosslessH.264

Comment: Yup it worked Sir.